# How to solve max() function.

Tags: functions

I have a question like this-

Q-What values does the function $f(x)=\max(x + 2,10)$ take for values of $x$ where  $0 \leq x \leq 20$ ?

I really don't know how to solve this. I tried a lot but couldn't. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when $8\leq x\leq 20$ then $x+2\geq 10$ thus $\max(x+2, 10)= x+2$ and where $x<8$ we have $x+2<10$  then $\max(x+2, 10)=10$

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 10&\; x<8  \\\\
x+2 & \; 8\leq x\leq 20
 \end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: thanks but could you please explain it more clearly. It matches as my books answer but I am unable to figure out.

Comment: when you choose max you want bigger number. when  $8\leq x\leq 20$ then  $10\leq x+2\leq 22$ thus $x+2$ is bigger than 10 so answer of $max(x+2, 10)=x+2$, but when $x<2$ you have $x+2<10$ this means 10 is bigger thus $max(x+2, 10)=10$.